# SharePoint date result wrong using CAML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, sharepoint, caml

I have made a search using CAML + JavaScript from a SharePoint list. In that list, there is date  column with value is `2020-01-01 00:00`, for example. When I run the code, the CAML give me the date `2019-12-31 23:00`.

Can someone help me?
Tks

Comment: The time returned from SharePoint is in UTC time zone.

Answer (score 0):

As Walker said,the time stored in SharePoint is in UTC time zone.

You could convert it to local time this way.
Append 'UTC' to the string before converting it to a date in javascript:

Demo: `new Date('5/8/2020 4:00:00 PM UTC').toLocaleString()`
[image]